# \Underfull badness(10000) error message

Tags: boxes, warnings

Can someone rectify this. Thanks in advance.

`\textbf{Sub interval 1:}($t_{o}-t_{1}$)\\\
This sub-interval starts when D1 and D4 are Forward biased, so in this sub-interval D1-D4 and D6-D7 are conducting Bridge voltages $V_{h1}$, $V_{h2}$ and primary current $i_{r1}$ is as shown in waveform. This sub-interval ends when current is commuted from D6-D7 to S6-S7and from D1-D4 to S1-S4. Hence for ZVS operation of S1 and S4, primary current \fbox{ $i_{r}(t_{0})<0$}.\\`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Possible related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108740/underfull-hbox-badness-10000-textbf?rq=1